# Control access to taxonomy terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms

In my project I have companies, which are taxonomy terms, which can create invoices. Users and companies are a many-to-many relationship. I'm able to control access to the invoices using tac_lite, but I've searched everywhere and can't find how to control access to the term page (/taxonomy/term/%). I want users to be able to see a list of their companies and a detailed page of each company, while denying access to other users' companies. Can I do that with tac_lite? If not, how can I approach this? Sorry if this is not the right place to ask and if this is an obvious problem, I'm new to Drupal.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/permissions-by-term, hope this can solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried before that module and from what I know it does basically the same thing as tac_lite. I can't control access to terms (to view their fields or a list of terms).